# Common interface for a function

Tags: c

I had this method(simplified):

```
void addraw(struct chain*a, uint8_t *data).
```

The point being I could call it from functions like:

```
void adduint16(struct chain*a, uint16_t val)
{
  uint8_t x[2] = {0};
  memcpy(x, &val, 2);

  addraw(chain, x);
}
```

Say now if I have method:

```
void addstr(struct chain*a, char* val)
```

I could easily do:

```
void addstr(struct chain*a, char* val)
{
   addraw(chain, (uint8_t*) val);
}
```

*But I think it is not always OK to pass `char *` as `uint8_t` pointer etc.*

So is having the addraw function such prototype better?

```
void addraw(struct chain*a, void *data)
```

would I avoid the cast problem? and still use Like I desire? e.g., with ints and strings as I showed above

Comment: This is C code. Not C#.

Comment: `uint8_t x[2] = {0};
  memcpy(x, &val, 2);` ... you only copy 16 bits of a 32-bit value?

Comment: @nneonneo Where are you getting 32-bits from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would [the prototype with `void*`] avoid the cast problem?

Yes, a prototype with `void*` will let you avoid casting pointers at the point of call.

> [can I] use Like I desire?

This depends on what you want to do: if you plan to interpret the data pointed to by the `data` pointer as data pointing to unsigned data, and pass signed data instead, you will get implementation-specific behavior. If all you need to do is copying "raw" data from one buffer to another, `void*` is a perfect choice.

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> But I think it is not always OK to pass `char *` as `uint8_t` pointer etc.

**Short answer:** You are right.

**Longer answer:** Depends on your platform if `char` on your platform is an unsigned integer value, you should be OK. If not, you are likely to run into problems associated with mixing signed and unsigned integer values.

The problem won't go away by changing the signature of `addraw` to:

```
void addraw(struct chain*a, void *data)
```

It'll appear to go away when you compile a file in which `adddraw` is used. However, inside `adddraw`, you have convert `data` to a pointer of either `uint8_t*` or `char*`. At that time, the problem of mixing signed and unsigned integers has to be dealt with.